# How to make a JButton run 2 commands?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, windowbuilder

I am coding a GUI quiz and I want it so that when I press "Start" It opens a new window which will be the start of the quiz <--- (Accomplished). I also want the other page I clicked "start" on to go away so there's only 1 window open when doing the quiz. I figured if I could add 2 commands to a JButton and activate  both of them with 1 click of the button it would work. Any help?

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");    
btnStart.setFont(newFont("HP Simplified Light", Font.PLAIN, 22));
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {       
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Frame2 nw = new Frame2();
         nw.NewScreen();
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the code for the second command right after where you put the code for the first one?

Comment: I suggest you do some research into CardLayout

Comment: Did you actually try adding two different ActionListeners to the same JButton?

Comment: @youtubefreak I tried that but It just exits it and doesn't run the second command

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I add 2 different ActionListeners?

Comment: `button.addActionListener(...)`

Comment: I added the code into the Question at the top can you tell me how to add 2 action listeners because I have 1 right now. Sorry bro I am a noob but I really need help..

Answer (score 0):

First way:

After nw.NewScreen(); add the Code to make first JFrame invisible.

Second way:

button.addActionListener(..)
  button.addActionListener(..) 
 adding 2 actionListeners to the same button.

But in your case just follow the first way.Except if your app lags until the new Frame is shown then you have to use Threads to show 
that something is loading.